# Do volunteer/elected moderators have access to detailed voting history data?

Tags: support, voting, moderators, moderator-abilities

Do volunteer/elected moderators have access to detailed voting histories? i.e. can they see which way individual users vote on specific questions, answers or comments?

Are there any plans to allow this in the future?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Volunteer moderators have very limited access to voting information.  The only voting information we can really see is related to anomalous voting patterns.  This makes it easier for us to spot sock puppet accounts.  We can't see specific votes cast on each question and answer by individual users. (So go ahead and feel free to downvote me, I can't do anything about it.)

I imagine the dev moderators (who have access to the full database) can see anything they want.

Comment: From what I've gathered, the devs don't have direct access to the production DB without deploying code in StackOverflow to do it for them.  Not that this would be impossible, just that it's not that clear-cut either.

Comment: But like most worlds, I'm sure production can become test or development due to backups getting restored in environments to keep the data fresh...

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can't see who votes on a question. This information is anonymous to all users.

Some server side process do however check voting patterns to look for strange activity. Since this information is truly anonymous anyone with database access can view this information verbatim.