# Is my flagging data/history anonymous to volunteer/elected moderators?

Tags: support, flags, moderators, moderator-abilities

Do volunteer/elected moderators get to see who raised a flag on a question, answer or comment, or are users who raise flags kept anonymous?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- spam/offensive flags are anonymous
- comment flags are anonymous
- moderator attention flags are attributed to the user who raised the flag, as Marc pointed out, so we can have a dialog if necessary or get background

Comment: Can you post a source for this (and similiar) information?

Comment: As of June '16 this [is no longer fully correct.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243715/allow-moderators-to-see-a-summary-of-flags-against-a-users-comments/280681#280681)

Answer (score 8):

We can see who raised a flag for moderator attention.

So don't flag something that I did, or I will smite you. :)

Comment: Goog thing too - in case some day someone disturbed enough turned *flagging abusive posts* into en masse *abusive flagging* of innocent posts. Probably useful in other scenarios as well.

Comment: What about emails to team@stackoverflow.com, do the volunteer/elected mods see these as well?

Comment: Emails to the team are not available to moderators.

Comment: Ian is right, that's not a group email address, although occasionally Jeff will forward an email to all of us if it's relevant.  I'm sure he won't divulge any sensitive information sent to him in an email.

Comment: Do you also see who upvotes/downvotes a post?

Comment: @Juan: No, not the details.  Kev asked that a few minutes earlier than this question. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/do-moderators-have-access-to-detailed-voting-history-data

Comment: @Bill - So you get to know if I flagged one of your posts?

Comment: @Kev: We can't really see the history of flags, but we can see who has flagged stuff that's still in the queue.  As soon as I process a flag and close it out it's gone from our view.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, spam/offensive flags are anonymous. It is only with "moderator attention" flags that we see the person raising it - which is reasonable, as sometimes we reply ;-p

Comment: How does a reply to a "moderator attention" flag show up?  As a comment or some other direct-to-user way?

Comment: There is no IM/PM in the system; if there is a need for a direct reply, I'd probably take it to e-mail.

Comment: What about flag question as duplicate / flag question to close / flag answer as not-an-answer / flag answer as very low quality? Are these flags anonymous?

Comment: @Pang for several of those, if it is closed the voters are shown in the "by..." text.