# Allow moderators to see a summary of flags against a user's comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, comment-flags

Moderators have easy access to all *posts* from a user that have been flagged (and how those flags were resolved), and we can see all comments from a user (including deleted ones).  This feature request is to give us some insight into (helpful) flags against a user's comments.

If a user has a pattern of problematic posts we'll see that, but I've seen users who leave many rude or non-constructive comments.  These get flagged, the moderator who sees the flag cleans them up, and life goes on.  It can take a while for the pattern to emerge because each moderator sees only part of the problem -- and has to rely on his memory.  Meanwhile, the user continues the activity and it can become more entrenched.  It would be better to be able to spot that early so we can talk with the user about it -- a stitch in time and all that.

I would like be able to see that a user's comments had N offensive flags, M not-constructive flags, and so on for the other flag reasons.  I can think of two places where this could be put in the interface:

1. On the flags page, add a summary with the counts by flag type.  Again, we only care about flags that were marked helpful.  If a user also receives spurious flags, well that's not his fault so *shrug*.  (As pointed out in a comment, we'd also need some indication of timing -- are these recent flags or old?)
2. On the "all comments" page, add information about flags to each comment.  This should be on the page itself, not behind "expander" widgets, so we can search the page easily.  Even better, just as we can filter for deleted and undeleted, add filters for flag types.

Option 1 gives us summary information only.  Option 2 gives us the details of which comments they were.  I don't know which would be easier to implement.  Either's fine with me.

We know that the information about the flag exists in the system, because (a) it shows up on the flagging user's "helpful flags" page and (b) it's in the timeline.  **This is a request to expose that information in a way that allows moderators to more-easily notice users with a pattern of problematic comments.**

Just giving us a total number of flagged comments doesn't address the need, because obsolete flags are usually not a sign of trouble.  Often, in fact, they're the sign of a helpful user -- the user commented with a question or suggestion, the post actually got fixed, and now the comment no longer applies.

[Related, narrower request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271914/162102).

Comment: I like this idea behind this, but I am curious about how possible it is design-wise. Since comments are second hand citizens, when deleted I assume they are fully removed without a trace. That is troublesome because without knowing about the removal, it can be hard to get numbers on it. If the numbers were collected in a different table, that would require a modification to the database. Perhaps they don't completely destroy deleted comments, in which case this should be pretty easy to implement.

Comment: @TravisJ Comments are soft-deleted, moderators can already see deleted comments.

Comment: For (1) do you mean the text of the comments would not be present? It would be nice to just put the deleted comment and flag on that same page. Without timeline/etc it's hard to make meaningful sense of that - let's say a user had 10 offensive comments, got mod messaged, and then _never_ got flagged again - that information would be lost.

Comment: @enderland that's a good point; we need some indication of when, which I hadn't considered.  (An earlier draft of this asked for *recent* flags, but I dropped that along the way and didn't properly clean up after it.)

Comment: @MadScientist - Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Slightly-refined version of this proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268664/162102

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of this morning, moderators will now be able to view comments by a specific user that have been flagged.  This is available in the moderator tools on the comments overview, on a new tab called "Flagged".

You will notice that we've also included some additional details like the type of comment flag (too chatty, not-constructive), who flagged the comment, and the outcome.  Each comment has an indicator next to it that will show if a flag is active or not. An active flag will be shown in red, and a processed flag will be shown in gray.

> [image]

Thanks to [Konamiman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136880/konamiman) for getting this implemented.

Comment: (Checks most-recent problem commenter's page.)  Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: That's great, thank you! Are there any plans to allow filtering by flag type? Specifically, the "offensive" ones? Many comments were flagged as simply "obsolete" or "too chatty" and it would be even greater if we could home in on the problematic ones.

Comment: @terdon It's on the back-burner for now, but I've got it on a list of things to still be done.

Comment: Back burner is fine, this is far from urgent. Thanks!

Comment: This effectively solves http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37345/166155

Comment: Not fully @DoubleAA because mods would like to see the info when presented with the comment flag.  Something like that will probably come later.

Comment: @bluefeet It's now guaranteed just a few clicks away. You used to have to check the flag histories of likely suspects, and even that wasn't a guaranteed success.

Comment: Minor thing, but the pagination on the page is broken; it seems to calculate the number of pages to show based on the `all` count, rather than the `flagged` count (and therefore always ends up showing numerous additional empty pages).

Comment: @Matt I reported that to the dev this morning, I'm sure he'll fix it.