# Show flags in comment history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, comment-flags

In the moderator timeline for a post, flags are indicated on comments (a number, with drill-down to see the specific types).  This is helpful for figuring out what happened on a *post*.  I'd like to see something similar for the deleted-comments view for a *user*.  We can easily see all of a user's comments (deleted and not) already; I'm asking for this one additional bit of signal to be added to that view, to make it easier for mods investigating complaints about patterns of inappropriate comments.

This request is a subset of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243715/162102), where I asked for aggregate information and filters.  I understand that that might be hard; even having this subset, which the timeline already supports (so I hope it's not too hard), would be very helpful.

Something like this:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Two questions, can mods see deleted comments, like forever and ever? And, if a comment is deleted within five minutes, i.e. the collocated edit time span, is it still visible?

Comment: @Mari-LouA the answer to #1 is yes, but I don't know the answer to #2.