# Is this reputation rollback because of a removed user correct?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, suggested-edits, deleted-accounts

I saw I lost some reputation over on [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) due to a removed user. Nothing unusual there.

Until I saw the details.

[image: screenshot of rep]

Now I know that [reputation gain for approved edits can be rolled back when the user who approved them is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249804/239016).

But it looks suspiciously like the 6 separate -2 rollbacks were added together for another full -12 rollback.

**Is that what happened?**

I'd like to note that a -12 is not *impossible*, but — knowing my voting history on that Stack — it *is* implausible.

Comment: Looks like the removed user approved **lots** of edits.

Comment: What do you mean it's implausible? It says it happened right there in your screenshot (if you want to know about that specific case you should really ask this on [Parenting Meta](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure it's a dupe. What I'd like to know is if the 6 -2's weren't added together and subtracted _again_.

Comment: @SQB something there is off, not sure what exactly, animuoson did say they'll change the logic, so I assume this will clear things up once done.

Comment: @Cai I thought about that, but I decided against it, since the mods there [can't see vote details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15942/239016).